# Bootstrap Footer, Full Width Of Page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, footer

i'm designing a website with joomla and using the bootstrap framework.
Now i have a problem by my footer. Basically i use a simple grid layout and i want the content part of the site in the center of the page with space on the left and the right side which i already achieved.
And now i want the footer not in the middle like the content but on the end of the page and over the whole width of it and NOT FIXED. So i want normally scroll down the page and at the end of it the footer shall appear with full width.
I searched for it a long time but i don' find any solution that worked.
I hope somebody can help me to achieve it...

In the following are the scripts of the php-page and the css file i used

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- main container -->
    <div class='container'>
        <!-- header -->
        <div class="mainMenuTop"/>
        <div class='row'>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="well" />
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <!-- main content area -->
            <div class='span12'>
                <div class="article">
                    <jdoc:include type="component" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer -->
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='span12'>
                <div class='footer'>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="none" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body 
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: url(../images/Test.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
 }

.article
{
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255); /* The Fallback */
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family:"Calibri", Times, serif;
}

.footer
{
    height: 50px;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
}
```

Kind Regards,
oodoloo

Answer (score 19):

You can put your footer to separate `<div class="container">` after the main content container. Then you can assign a container class which does not limit the width of the footer, like happens with main content. E.g.::

```
<div class="container">
      ...
</div>
<div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I tried this, but that was not enough for my needs. Now i dont know how i could achieve that the div fills out the full page. And when i set a fix width the div only enlarges to the right side, the left side begins already at the point where the content starts.
Can you help me once more please?

Comment: Can you create an isolated and repeatable example shared on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io? Unless you can read and edit the actual code, without too much effort, only general advices can be given.

Comment: Ok, here [jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxmv7/) i created an example. For the footer at the end i want to achieve the result i described in my first post. Hope this helps to solve the problem.

For the reproduction what i described in my last comment you have to add to the footer css 'width: 800px' or 'width: 1500px' for example.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa is correct. This does achieve a full-width footer as described in the OP. In the fiddle provided by oodoloo, the footer div is incorrectly within the main contaner div...which is why it doesn't work - it needs to be outside. The row within the container-fluid footer is important as this will remove the 15px left and right padding that Bootstrap adds to conatiner-fluid.

Answer (score 4):

for my needs, now i fixed it like you can see here:
[jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxmv7/3/)

```
.footer
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have added "width: 100%", "position: absolute", "left: 0" and "right:0" to the css-class ".footer".
I think decisive was the "position: absolute".
Then i have to add the "left: 0" because the left side doesnt take the fullsize. after adding this it does.
The "right: 0" i added, because of completeness. Doesnt know if it is needed in any other browser. Here it works also without it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't get my footer to span the entire width of the page. I used Chrome Dev Tools to see what was blocking the footer from expanding. I found that the problem was where I used the "Container" class. It adds padding each time and for some reason the footer would not be able to span past that padding on the page, even though it was in a separate div. I changed the container divs to have the "container-fluid" class and removed the padding for the "container-fluid" class in my CSS. The footer works now and the containers are still responsive. I had to manually adjust some of the elements which needed extra padding for my styling. Not sure if this is the proper solution but it worked for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I do this and it is right:

```
@media(max-width:500px){

    .footer{
        float:left;
        width:109%;
        margin-left:-5%;
    }

}
```