# Bootstrap 3 full browser width footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make this standard Bootstrap 3 footer behave exactly as the stackoverflow.com footer you can see at the bottom of this page? Full browser window width colored background and text bounded by page width. I tested all the other stackoverflow post on the subject and nothing works for my page. My page HTML is below.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Roadmap</title>
    <link href="/Content/css?v=Bz3KZjU_pdOm2wAVr7z_ylCuQzQDs1O8N6pV4cvXc_Q1" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script> 
</head>

<body style="padding-top:0">

<div class="container" style="position: relative">

    <div align="right" class="body-content" style=" margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px;">

    <p style="display: inline; width: 1%; font-size: 90%; background-color: white; opacity: 0.8; padding: 3px; ">
    <a href="/Account/Register">Register</a> | <a href="/Account/LogIn">Log in</a>
    </p>

</div>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">

<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/" ><img src="/Assets/images/logo.png"></a>            
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Product<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Image Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">What&#39;s New</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/Support">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li><a href="/Download">Download</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

        <div class="container body-content" style="height:200px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5" style="color:White">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 60px">Roadmap</h1>
                    <p style="font-size:1.2em; font-weight:lighter">Upcoming release</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- position absolute clears right margin, we set it again -->
        <div class="container body-content">

        <h2>Version 9.0</h2>
        <p>Planned for Q4 2015</p>
        <hr>
        <footer>
           <p class="pull-right" style="font-size: 85%;">
           <a href="/Store/Purchase_Terms" style="margin-right: 20px">Purchase terms and conditions</a>
           <a href="/Home/Privacy_Policy" style="margin-right: 20px">Privacy policy</a>
           <a href="/Company/Contact">Contact</a></p>
           <p style="font-size: 85%; line-height: 180%">Copyright &copy; 2015 - CompanyName</p>
        </footer>
   </div>           
    <script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=2Fz3B0iizV2NnnamQFrx-NbYJNTFeBJ2GM05SilbtQU1"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: What's not working? What needs to be fixed? Saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help us help you.

Comment: This footer is the standard bootstrap one. I need help in changing it as required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Footer, Full Width Of Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970117/bootstrap-footer-full-width-of-page)

Comment: @Kristof: No, we are talking of full browser window width here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the footer out of the div with the ".container" class.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Roadmap</title>
  <link href="/Content/css?v=Bz3KZjU_pdOm2wAVr7z_ylCuQzQDs1O8N6pV4cvXc_Q1" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>
 </head>
 <body style="padding-top:0">
  <div class="container" style="position: relative">
    <!-- Page Content Here -->
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Footer content here -->
    </div>
  </footer>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add a nested `<div class="container body-content">` for perfect alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the footer content in a container, so...

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="pull-right" style="font-size: 85%;">
            <a href="/Store/Purchase_Terms" style="margin-right: 20px">Purchase terms and conditions</a>
            <a href="/Home/Privacy_Policy" style="margin-right: 20px">Privacy policy</a>
            <a href="/Company/Contact">Contact</a>
       </p>
       <p style="font-size: 85%; line-height: 180%">Copyright &copy; 2015 - CompanyName</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Ahh, @ReLeaf beat me to it!

Comment: Haha, sorry @mtt_g! The other important thing to note is that the footer needs to be outside of the container to span full width, but other than that yours is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but you should play around with adjusting the padding and margins in your body and footer styles. Bootstrap adds padding as a default so adjusting the left and right padding and maybe margins to 0 might help. I can't tell you exactly what it is based in your code but I have run into this problem before and it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I'm quite sure you are talking about the margin, in css, you must remove it in body.
Like this

```
body{margin: 0px;}
```

Comment: The Browser reset it actually integrated in the bootstrap css file, so, I don't think it's that.

Comment: I need to change only footer width, not the other page sections.