# My footer does not take the whole length of the page - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I know that the question has already been asked several times, but I did not find any solution suited to my case, I tried to put a container-fluid as specified on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970117/bootstrap-footer-full-width-of-page), but it does not seem to work.

Everything is going well, but when I add my footer, it does not take the whole length of the page, or of the row, there are padding caused by that of the container-fluid.

Here is a picture representing the problem :

[image]

*As you can see, the borders do not complete the entire length*

Here is a photo of when I remove the padding from my container-fluid which includes all of my main :

[image]

*As you can see, a overflow-x appears*

So my question is, do I have to worry about fixing the overflow problem, or putting my footer on the whole length ? I don't know which track should I take !

My HTML footer :

```html
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email_newsletter">S'inscrire gratuitement à la Newsletter :</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email_newsletter" class="form-control w-50 email" aria-describedby="email_newsletter_note">
                            <small id="email_newsletter_note" class="form-text text-muted">Nous ne partageons en aucun cas vos informations.</small>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a href="">Mentions Légales</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: The overflow is the cause of either your footer being of wrong width or parent element not properly formed. Add code to your question. The footer needs to be outside the container fluid.

Comment: Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/album/

Comment: When I put my footer out of the container-fluid, the overflow appears, so if I understand correctly, I have to solve the problem of my overflow while leaving the footer out of the container-fluid, is it?

Comment: The `row` class has margin left as negative in bootstrap because of default padding in container/container-fluid. So, move footer outside and then add container class to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code gives the whole length footer of the page

```
<footer class="page-footer">

      <!-- Footer Links -->
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">

            <!-- Content -->
            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Footer Content</h5>
            <p>Here you can use rows and columns to organize your footer content.</p>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->


        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->

      </div>
      <!-- Footer Links -->

      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright:
        <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->

    </footer>
    <!-- Footer -->
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution :**

My footer was in a container-fluid, it was enough to bring it out of there and to add a container-fluid to my footer itself :

```html
<footer id="footer" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email_newsletter">S'inscrire gratuitement à la Newsletter :</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email_newsletter" class="form-control w-50 email" aria-describedby="email_newsletter_note">
                            <small id="email_newsletter_note" class="form-text text-muted">Nous ne partageons en aucun cas vos informations.</small>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a href="">Mentions Légales</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```