# Why is footer not filing the full screen width html/Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, width, footer

No matter what I try, my footer is not filling the full screen width. What can I do?

body width 100%  did not work

I tried this, too: [Bootstrap Footer, Full Width Of Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970117/bootstrap-footer-full-width-of-page)

I am working in Angular 11 & Bootstrap 5.

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row  align-items-center">
    <div class="contentLeftCorner col-sm-4">
      <div class="footerComponents me-5" >sth</div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentCenter col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="contentRightCorner col-sm-4">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="footerComponents me-5">1</div>
          <div class="footerComponents me-5">2</div>
          <div class="footerComponents me-5">3</div>
          <div class="footerComponents me-5">4</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="footerComponents 5 me-5">a</div>
          <div class="footerComponents 5 me-5">b</div>
          <div class="footerComponents 5 me-5">c</div>
          <div class="footerComponents 5 me-5">d</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .footerComponents:hover {
  cursor:pointer ;
  color: dimgrey;
}

.footerComponents{
  border-color: transparent;
}

//no borders on clicked element
*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.contentRightCorner {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the CSS of the classes not included in BS5? I can help you, but need some more info on them. Have you provided the html of the whole footer section?

Comment: I edited my post and put the CSS, too. Shouldn't be necessary as there isn´t information about what  is needed. I don´t understand what you mean with "Have you provided the html of the whole footer section?" 

I use it in the app.component.html 

But even If I use it seperately in the index.html the footer is still not full screen width.

Comment: I checked it. It's showing full-width. Your code is _working perfectly_. The container is taking full screen width. If you are asking about the components not filling the full width, then **there is a margin of 3rem on the right side for `footerComponents`**. If you can share an image of what you want to achieve, it would be clear to understand.

Comment: I editied my post with an image. I want to achieve a responsible footer. On https://twitter.com/ you can see an example of a footer that is responsible and full width, like I want, too. It seems to be dependent on the div. If i just put a simple <h1> instead of the footer code, it shows the full width. But I don`t understand why this is happening as there is no code saying to format it like this.

Comment: Where does the 3rem come from? I did not set this anywhere.

Comment: That was from me-5 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.conatainer`'s `padding` to 0, and `.row`'s `width` to 100% and remove gutter position on `.row`. Also remove `me-5` class from `footerComponents`.

```css
.container {
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.footerComponents {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-beta2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-beta2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="contentLeftCorner col-sm-4">
      <div class="footerComponents">sth</div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentCenter col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="contentRightCorner col-sm-4">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="footerComponents">1</div>
          <div class="footerComponents">2</div>
          <div class="footerComponents">3</div>
          <div class="footerComponents">4</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="footerComponents">a</div>
          <div class="footerComponents">b</div>
          <div class="footerComponents">c</div>
          <div class="footerComponents">d</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note: I have added background-color and border properties to show the exact positions.

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to your `footerComponents` being inside of `<div>` with the class `container`. As Bootstrap 5 has set a `max-width` for the `container` class on certain size screen. The `container` class is only 100% on extra small screen. You can refer to the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/).

```
.container            max-width
Extra small <576px  : 100%
Small ≥576px        : 540px
Medium ≥768px       : 720px
Large ≥992px        : 960px
X-Large ≥1200px     : 1140px
XX-Large ≥1400px    : 1320px
```

You can try and bring the `footerComponents` `<div>` outside of the `container` `<div>` for this.

The other option is to go with `container-fluid` class which is `100%` at all breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Put it outside of container DIV.